# Calculating a sequence of numbers using the while loop in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to return a sequence of numbers using the `while` loop, starting with the input value `num` and ending with 1. For example:

```
>>> tray(8)
[8, 2, 1]
```

If the number is even, I'd like it to replace `num` with the integer value of `num`**0.5, and if it's odd it should replace `num` with the integer value of `num`**1.5.

```
def tray(num):
    '''returns a sequence of numbers including the starting
    value of num and ending value of 1, replacing num with
    integer value of num**0.5 if even and num**1.5 if odd'''
    while num != 1:
        if num %2 == 0:
            num**=0.5
        else:
            num**=1.5
        return num
```

I'm sort of lost on how to make sure the replacements are integers - if I try `int(num**0.5)` it comes back with "invalid syntax." Additionally, it's only returning the answer of `num**0.5` and I can't figure out how to return the starting value `num` along with the sequence up to 1. Thanks for any input.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Comment: What is the exact code that gives the "invalid syntax" error?

Comment: Suggestion: You might want to learn about `yield`.

Comment: Are you aware that you never reach 1 when you exponent is 1.5 and your input number is >= 1?

Comment: The "invalid syntax" error comes in a pop up when I try to run the module and it highlights [this equals sign](http://i.imgur.com/jkM4eVs.png)

Comment: @timgeb, the exponent is 1.5 when the input number is odd only up until it becomes an even number, then the exponent should change to 0.5 until `num` becomes 1

Comment: That is a syntax error because you are effectively doing `int(num = num**0.5)` ditch the equal sign and do `num = int(num**0.5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These adjustments fix the errors in your code

```
def tray(num):
    '''returns a sequence of numbers including the starting
    value of num and ending value of 1, replacing num with
    integer value of num**0.5 if even and num**1.5 if odd'''
    seq = [ num ]
    while num != 1:
        if num %2 == 0:
            num = int(num**0.5)
        else:
            num = int(num**1.5)

        seq.append( num )

    return seq
```

Here rewritten as a generator.

```
def tray(num):
    '''returns a sequence of numbers including the starting
    value of num and ending value of 1, replacing num with
    integer value of num**0.5 if even and num**1.5 if odd'''
    yield  num
    while num != 1:
        if num %2 == 0:
            num = int(num**0.5)
        else:
            num = int(num**1.5)

        yield num
```

which can be used to create a list like this.

```
list( tray(8) )
```

Comment: added adjustments to generator

Answer (score 0):

The generator version:

```
def tray(n):        
    while n > 1:
        expo = 1.5 if n%2 else 0.5
        yield n
        n = int(n**expo)
    yield 1
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(tray(8))
[8, 2, 1]
>>> list(tray(7))
[7, 18, 4, 2, 1]
```